# passing var as string to an array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

Im sure this is super simple.
im trying to pass values held in a var into another var as an array.

I have a var `$guideinValue` that contains string of values separated by commas. the values stand for category ids.

when i `echo` `$guideinValue` it shows `18,19` which are the proper category id's.
im trying to use these in the wordpress var `$selected_cats`.

when i manually punch into `$selected_cats = array(18,19);` everything works
and a print_r  of 1$selected_cats1 shows `Array ( [0] => 18 [1] => 19 )`

but when i use `$selected_cats = array($guideinValue);`, a `print_r` shows `Array ( [0] => 18,19 )` and nothing works ofc

Why does this happen and how do i fix my syntax?

Comment: `$selected_cats = explode(',', $guideinValue);` you'll get output in array format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple use `explode` function.

```
array explode ( string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit ] );
```

Working example:

```
$array = explode(",", $guideinValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the proper way with array_values(), array_filter() and explode()

```
$selected_cats = array_values(array_filter(explode(',', $guideinValue)));
```

`explode()` - Breaks string

`array_filter()` - Clears empty values

`array_values()` - Rearrange array indexes to start from 0